# ncurses in Haskell for Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, ncurses

I've written a program in Haskell that's going to be run on a Windows 7 machine. It's not my machine. I don't get to choose the OS.

It's been written using the [ncurses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses) package, and compiles just fine on my (Ubuntu) machine.  Unfortunately, it won't compile on Windows, even under Cygwin.  It gives me a very unhelpful error (Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1) when it tries to build the ncurses package.

I've tried specifying the exact locations of the header and dll files for ncurses to no avail.

Is there anything I can do, **short of re-writing the software to use a different package?**

In hindsight, I should've checked that it would compile under Windows some time ago, but since I've successfully used ncurses in C on Windows in the past, I had no reason to believe it wouldn't work.

My current code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/mtlstats/mtlstats).

**Edit:** If I were to re-write the IO parts using something else (as an absolute last resort) I would need to be able to do the following things:

- determine the number of rows and columns in the terminal
- be notified if the terminal is resized
- be notified when a key is pressed (including arrow keys and function keys, without line buffering)
- control the position and visibility of the cursor
- disable echoing of standard input
- change text/background colour

...and I would need to be able to do these things in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: "It gives me a very unhelpful error (Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1)" Are you sure that there isn't more to the error than that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't trust the computer I'm compiling on with my StackOverflow credentials, so I can't copy/paste, but the more complete error message is:

-- While building package ncurses-0.2.16 using:

[ridiculously long command stack is using to compile it]

Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1

Comment: I cannot answer your question other than to validate that I have never successfully gotten haskell ncurses to install in any variation of Windows 10 / postix compatibility layer either. It seems to require too much coordination between gcc, ln, and ghc for cabal to manage successfully.

Comment: So far, my final solution has been to install it under the Linux subsystem for Windows 10.  Still looking for a better alternative.